# jQuery and CSS3 transitions on a slider

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

**I'm attempting to understand why this works in ie8**

example 1:  http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/

**But this doesn't**

example 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/MobsterFiddle/6RAEP/

The both use css3 transitions yet for reasons I'm not aware, my fiddle (example 2) won't work:

```
 -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
```

**My guess is it's something to do with this.**

```
 marketSlide.css({
            transform: 'translate(' + (-100 * (current - 1)) + '%, 0)',
            WebkitTransform: 'translate(' + (-100 * (current - 1)) + '%, 0)',
```

In the first example (example 1) the jQuery is being used like this:

```
.css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * -450+"px)");
```

What is the difference between the two and why doesn't the one that works use `translateX`

Thanks!

Comment: I tried both in IE8 and neither of them work - in fact, JSFiddle is completely broken in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support CSS3 transforms. You will have to use Modernizr tests in order to fall back to normal [jQuery animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for IE8.

Also, check if you're running Chrome Frame in IE8. The example site you gave only works with Chrome Frame, and not with native IE8.

Comment: I didn't know it, but our local is using Chrome wrapper so the internal people can use Gmail.  Thanks for pointing that out!